# Error BC30420 'Sub Main' not found when using Roslyn to create Console App

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to compile VB.Net code at runtime so that I can do some analysis.

Currently I am struggling to get the compilation working as it claims to be unable to locate Sub Main. It claims success when I compile as a DLL but when referenced I can't see anything in the object browser which leads me to believe that it isn't working properly either.

```
var compilationOptions = new VisualBasicCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication, mainTypeName: "SomeModule");
var compilation = VisualBasicCompilation.Create("ExampleCompilation", null, null, compilationOptions);
var syntaxTree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
    Imports System

    Module SomeModule

        ''' <summary>
        ''' This is the summary for Main()
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub Main()
            Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"")
        End Sub
    End Module
");

compilation.SyntaxTrees.Add(syntaxTree);

EmitResult er = null;

using (Stream xmlStream = new StreamWriter("output.xml").BaseStream)
using (Stream peStream = new FileStream("output.exe", FileMode.Create))
{
    er = compilation.Emit(peStream, null, xmlStream, null, null, new EmitOptions());
}

if (er.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("FAILURE");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", er.Diagnostics));
}
```

This code outputs the error in the title (BC30420), produces a 0 byte executable, and an xml file containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<assembly>
<name>
ExampleCompilation
</name>
</assembly>
<members>
</members>
</doc>
```

Is this the correct approach for doing VB compilation with Roslyn or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mainTypeName` in your CompilationOptions should be fully qualified ("SomeModule.SomeClass" in your example), and must either be directly in a module or be `Shared`.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work so far. I have updated my original question to reflect the changes I have made since your answer. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: `Compilation` is an immutable type, so `compilation.SyntaxTrees.Add(syntaxTree);` does not change your `compilation`. Try adding the syntax tree to the `Compilation.Create` call.  Also, you will some references (at least to mscorlib.dll for `Object` and such).

Comment: Excellent, this solved my problem, thank you! I have other errors because I didn't tell it where to find System but I was expecting that.